# Going through The C Programming Language K&R in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, c, education

From what I have read, K&R seems to be a good place to start learning programming in general, and C programming specifically. However, I've just started the first chapter and I have a few questions. They may be extremely simple, and I apologize if that's the case (I am new, after all) -- but your helping me answer them would be very appreciated.

1) I understand the book is written to describe C languages in general. Does this mean the examples they give are just rough outlines, and that for me to attempt them myself I have to "translate" the general outline given into C++ or C# or whatever?

For example, the textbook gives this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 main()
 {
 printf("hello, world\n");
 }
```

But I've found a program to print "Hello, world" in C#, for example is:

```
// A Hello World! program in C#. 
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello 
    {
        static void Main() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And the program in C++ looks different from both the above...

So my question is: does the book expect me to be able to translate the first program (or outline, whatever it is) to a C# or C++ program -- I am using Visual Studio -- to be able to practice myself?

2) If the book does expect me to do this, do you all have any tips on how I can go about translating general C code to C# or C++.

3) This may be opinion, but which should I base my learning on (and practice coding in) -- C# or C++?

Comment: I have no idea why learning C have anything to do with C++ and C#... one at a time please. Sometimes it is not possible to directly translate something in one language to another language (or it will be very very bad to do so)

Comment: All these other languages came after C. K&R do not "expect" you to do use anything else - their book is for learning C.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C#. C# is actually much closer to Java than either C or C++. Trying to learn C# from K&R would be analogous to trying to learn modern Italian from a textbook on Latin.

Comment: @JoeBallard I think that suggests that C is "less advanced," which isn't true -- a better comparison might be trying to learn Italian from a French textbook. Both Romance languages, but not informative for "Romance languages in general."

Comment: Your confusion seem to be caused by the similar names. C, C++ and C# are different languages, with C# having nothing in common with C. There is no such thing like "C languages". And Visual Studio is a development environment, which is a fancy name for a complex code editor. It is used to write programs in many unrelated languages - but many people associate it with C#.

Comment: These are quite different languages. C++ is inspired by C and C# is inspired by C++ and Java, but they are by no means the same language, not by a long (or "long int", in C) shot.

Comment: I would definitely not recommend learning C++ and C# from K&R, furthermore, I would advise against most people learning C as a first programming language. C is quite a hard language - it is much closer to the machine than most modern languages. Instead, I'd recommend learning something like Haskell if you have a strong maths background, and something like Python otherwise. I'd only recommend C if you are an electrical engineer or something. Programming skills are easy to transfer between langauges - I think it would be better to learn to program in an easy language first.

Comment: @Patrick I see your point, but I didn't intend it that way. Like C, Latin is older, but not less advanced.

Answer (score 36):

> I understand the book is written to describe C languages in general.

[The book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) is written to teach you `ANSI C`, not 'C languages in general'

> Does the book expect me to be able to translate the first program ... to a C# or C++ program?

No, those are different languages, and the book does not expect you to do *anything* with those languages. The examples are `ANSI C` examples.

> Do you all have any tips on how I can go about ...
>
> Which should I base my learning on (and practice coding in) -- C# or C++?

Those questions, while perfectly fine, are off-topic for this site.

Suffice it to say, if you want to learn C# or C++, you should seek out resources for those specific languages.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, let me agree that K&R is a great place to start with the C family. It is a really wonderfully written book. Importantly, it is quite concise.

Be aware that C++ is much more closely related to C that C#, although C# does borrow heavily from both. Java in fact does the same, and indeed C# followed from Java.

You can't learn C# or C++ just using K&R - you need resources for each of those.

You seem to be proposing learning all three of C, C++ and C# simultaneously. Whether this is a good thing depends on you. It will give you a great opportunity to compare and contrast the languages without having built up a prejudice from whichever you learn first.

However, this may prove very challenging. Ask yourself, if you wanted to learn Spanish, Portuguese and Italian, would you learn them at the same time or separately?

Comment: +1, especially for the natural language simile - it's quite applicable.

Answer (score 0):

The K&R book is a great place to start with any of the C variants.

The short answer is that you can run C code through a C++ compiler and it will run.

Some things you need to know:

- When C++ was introduced, it updated C's capabilities by (at a minimum) adding object oriented coding to C. (**UPDATE**) As many of you have noted, the languages are not the same, continuing to grow further apart with time. (**/UPDATE**). According to the wikipedia article, [Compatibility of C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B), there are semantic differences:

> The C and C++ programming languages are closely related. C++ grew out of C, as it was designed to be source-and-link compatible with C.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B) Due to this, development tools for the two languages (such as IDEs and compilers) are often integrated into a single product, with the programmer able to specify C or C++ as their source language. **However, due to minor semantic differences, most non-trivial C programs will not compile as C++ code without modification — C++ is not a superset of C.** *Emphasis added*.

- C++ compilers (specifically VS) typically will run C code with minor or no modifications depending on the complexity of your program. You may have to set various compiler/linker options. This will depend on which compiler and version you are using. Take a look at [Compiling a C/C++ Program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk21sfcf.aspx). And [What issues can I expect compiling C code with a C++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861517/what-issues-can-i-expect-compiling-c-code-with-a-c-compiler). Also check out [Running C in a C++ compiler](http://www.google.com/search?q=running+c+in+c%2B%2B).
- C# is a newer language that has distanced itself from its C roots, so you will have to translate C to C# to get it to work. [What are the differences between C, C# and C++ in terms of real-world application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692225/what-are-the-differences-between-c-c-sharp-and-c-in-terms-of-real-world-appli).

> Both C and C++ give you a lower level of abstraction that, with increased complexity, provides a breadth of access to underlying machine functionality that are not necessarily exposed with other languages. C++ adds the convenience (reduced development time) of a fully object oriented language which can, potentially, add an additional performance cost.
>
> C# provides a managed memory model that adds a higher level of abstraction again. This level of abstraction adds convenience and improves development times, but complicates access to lower level APIs and makes specialized performance requirements problematic.

Comment: I don't agree that C++ extends C because the two languages have diverged by miles C++ is really a replacement to C additionally VSC++ is also managed

Comment: C has things which C++ does not (`restrict`, type-generics, implicit conversion from `void*`, for example). A C program is not necessarily a valid C++ program even if it doesn't use any C++-only keywords.

Comment: (I have no enough rep on this site to do -1, but consider this a downvote) *"C++ extends C by (at a minimum) adding object oriented coding to C"* If you think that you doesn't know anything neither of C and C++ nowadays: C With Clases was the "beta" of C++ and dates from the middle of the eighties, and C have evolved a lot since K&R (In fact as others noticed C and C++ have diverged). I understand that people still rely on classic books because many people used them at the time they are learning and that books where awesome, but **we should update our bibliographies**. In the case of ...

Comment: ... C++ there are many efforts to update the books, and in fact I will never recommend anybody to read *TC++PL 3th ed* having a version updated for C++11. The same applies (Or should apply) for C. **Stop using K&R for learning, there is C99 and C11, ANSI C is just very old**

Comment: Ah *"C++ compilers (specifically VS) typically will run C code unmodified"* About this: VS is not the best example of a good and compliant compiler. Don't use it as an example. Microsoft does whatever they like, providing a compiler which **has no C official support** (Until VS2013, where they say that C99 implementation was finished) and neither a C++ support (They are still writting some points of the C++98 standard, and the C++11 support is just a joke)

Comment: "C++ compilers (specifically VS) typically will run C code unmodified" - no. What you mean is "Many C++ compilers also have options to make them C compilers", but a valid C++ compiler **won't** compile all C code. MSVC pretty much won't compile a single idiomatic C program (all those implicit conversions from `void*` due to malloc mostly) if you don't tell it explicitly to    compile the source as C.

Comment: @Ramhound, yes the languages have diverged significantly. However, they are not the same and never have been. VSC++ can also be run in a non-managed (native) process.

Comment: @Manu343726, while VC++ is not the best C/C++ compiler available (**note:** I never stated a preference for any compiler), according to Microsoft's own documentation, it will compile plain C code: [Compiling a C/C++ Program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk21sfcf.aspx).

Comment: @AdamZuckerman - Which was sort of my point. C++ can compile C syle C++ code. People often do not understand that simple fact. Actually you also made this mistake. **VC++ has two compilers one is a C compiler and the other is a C++ compiler**.  Your right the managed code is typically called C++/CLI

Comment: I do not see that C# has C roots. It borrows some syntax, that's it. C# has Java roots. I think it's widely accepted that the name was chosen for marketing reasons. That's in fact someone should always think about: C# - in contrast to C, C++, Java - is proprietary, only useful to learn if you are hooked to this kind of platform.

Comment: @Zane How is C# any more proprietary than any other language with published specification and available open source compilers? Actually, I'd say C# is better in this regard than C and C++, since its specification (the actual thing, not just some draft) is available for free.

Comment: @svick Whatever you call it - your comment shows one more reason why C# does not belong into the same class as C, C++.

Answer (score -2):

From a c# perspective K&R might be a great book on c ... i recently read it in an attempt to brush up on c. I have to say the code in it makes my eyes bleed (when having a c# hat on).

In c# the current style is to make everything clear and not ram 4+ statements into one.

If you want to learn c# this is not the place to start. I cannot recommend a book however. But c, c++ and c# are completely separate languages.

c is amazing in its simplicity and elegance. Its a bit stone age in its processes but going back to its simplicity was something i found rewarding. And highly inspiring because entire operating systems are built on this without all the stuff that is essential to c#

c# is enterprisey and is very good at it.

c++ has evolved so much over the years, learning it from a c perspective is a bad idea as so much has been learnt and rebuilt over time. you want to start from a very modern approach to avoid the horrible bits imo.